# Why is my ${user.home} variable resoled at build time

Tags: maven, yeoman, spring-boot, jhipster

I have a JHipster generated application with an YAML property file that looks like this:

```
storage:
      location: ${user.home}/my/folder
```

My problem is that the variable ${user.home} is resolved at build time, when I run `mvn package` (on Jenkins). So the property is already resolved in the resulting artifact, hence when I deploy on on my server, that path contains the resolved home of the user Jenkins.
Anybody know who is doing this and why? I was expecting that the variable would be resolved at runtime.

Thanks.
Valentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure of how JHipster builds on top of Spring Boot, but my guess would be that it's Maven's resource filtering that's expanding `${user.home}` at build time. It's [enabled by default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent/pom.xml#L42-L56) by `spring-boot-starter-parent` for `application.properties` and `application.yaml` in `src/main/resources`.

This [Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1199) contains some more information, along with details of a configuration change that you may like to make so that `${…}` entries are no longer filtered:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <delimiters>
            <delimiter>@</delimiter>
        </delimiters>
        <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```